# sudoers entry allowing group to run as group with no password

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

I want to add an entry to sudoers that will allows users in the group `test` to run any command on any host as the group `test` (i.e., with `sudo -g test`, without having to type a password. I've tried a few different ways of doing this that were syntactically valid, but none of them work as intended. I guess I'm not really sure where I should put the `NOPASSWD` option to make it apply to `sudo -g`. Any thoughts? This is on Ubuntu 13.10 server, btw.

Comment: Errr… if the users already are a member of the test group, why do you need `sudo`? It wouldn't be adding any permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should work with this: `%test ALL=(:test) NOPASSWD:ALL`  What /etc/sudoers config do you have that gives you problems?  And what error do you see when you try?

*Edit:  Not sure exactly which powers you want your group to have.*